# Manual Facebook login for website - Inspecting Access Tokens

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I referred this Facebook page [Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/) to build a login script for my website.

Here is the summary of steps from the page above:

1. Get authorization code
2. Exchanging Code for an Access Token
3. Inspecting Access Tokens
4. Query Graph Api

On the third step Facebook requires the below parameters

```
(I used the access token from step 2 here)
input_token   {token-to-inspect}

// An app access token or an access token for a developer of the app.
(Should i use my FB app id ?)
access_token  {app-token-or-admin-token}
```

What should the access_token contain? I inserted my FB app id but got the below response

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_token" "Invalid OAuth access token."
```

Not sure if the error is due to expired user access token or because of wrong input parameter.

Comment: The latter. An app id is not a token. If you are unsure about tokens, then use the side navigation on that documentation page you are already on, and read up on them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I read further and found this page about [app access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens)

You can either generate an app access token

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
?client_id=your-app-id
&client_secret=your-app-secret
&redirect_uri=your-redirect-url
&grant_type=client_credentials"
```

or set access_token parameter as below

```
access_token=your-app_id|your-app_secret
```

I tried the latter your-app_id|your-app_secret  and it worked.